# use a string in SELECT clause on knex js (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Hi I would like to include a string value to SELECT clause on KnexJS. It worked fine on Postgresql, but I am not sure how to convert that query into Knex syntax.

Here is Postgresql:

```
select date, 'UNFINISHED' from task_history
where store_id=1 and date=20160527
```

Here is Knex:

```
await db.table('task_history')
.count('*')
.select('date', knex.raw("UNFINISHED"))
.where({ 
     store_id: request.params.storeid,
     finish_time: null 
}) 
.whereBetween('date', [request.params.sdate, request.params.edate])                    
.groupBy('date')
```

Knex one gives me an error saying that there is no column called UNFINISHED. "UNFINISHED" is a string value that I would like to return with the query result.

I've tried to use knex.raw() as mentioned first solution below, but somehow, I could not use knex.raw(). Maybe that's because of 'await'? I am not sure.

Update: .select('date', db.raw("'UNFINISHED'")) Just a single quote missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For literal strings use knex.raw()

```
db.table('task_history')
.select('date', db.raw("UNFINISHED"))
.where({store_id:1, date:20160527})
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried, but still no luck. It says - column "[object Object]" does not exist

Comment: Thank you so much EoinS. Sorry for bothering you again.
Here is the full code snippet i am dealing with.. it seems like it doesn't accept knex.raw there.
    
    await db.table('task_history')
                    .count('*')
                    .select('date', knex.raw("UNFINISHED"))
                    .where({ 
                        store_id: request.params.storeid,
                        finish_time: null 
                    }) 
                    .whereBetween('date', [request.params.sdate, request.params.edate])                    
                    .groupBy('date')

Comment: Not at all!!  Good question.  There seems to have been issues with this I am still researching.

Comment: knex.raw caused the error. - message: knex is not defined stack: ReferenceError: knex is not defined

Comment: Thank you for the update. Somehow, I can't include knex.raw in the join clause.

Comment: It worked when I changed it like - select('date, db.raw("'UNFINISHED'"). I really appreciate for your help!!

Comment: Awesome, good work!  There isn't much literature on this, so hopefully this answer can help others!

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. May i ask?

Comment: Sure, maybe open a new question , comment here with a link and I'll see what I can do (with help from SO!)

Comment: I've already opened a new question and waiting for the answer :)

Comment: here is the link
    
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474970/division-on-date-in-the-select-clause-on-knex-js-postgres

Comment: Only on mobile that one will take opening python shell, mañana!!

Comment: Are you having a difficulty to open the link?
For a nutshell, the question is that I have a column(date)'s value (20160527) and would like to divide that value by 100.
The query I use is selet( 'date as yyyymm'), but I don't know where I apply the division.